# issue using RichImageSelector in a repeater control : javascript error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having issue using `RichImageSelector` in a `Repeater` control.

The code works fine for the first row and for subseqent rows i get javascript error.

Onclick of a button new row of similar controls gets formed.

When i click on newly created `RichImageSelector` control i  get javascript error as

```
Unable to get value of the property 'LaunchPicker': object is null or undefined
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Suggest you move this to normal Stack Exchange. Sounds like a .Net related issue

Comment: @Fox `RichImageSelector` is a Sharepoint Control, for other controls there is no issue.